# DataGrid sorts again after Sorting event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, sorting, datagrid

Im trying to sort multiple columns without using the shift key using the `DataGridSortingEvent` with these codes:

```
private void dataGridPayables_Sorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Column.SortDirection == null)
            e.Column.SortDirection = ListSortDirection.Descending;

        ListSortDirection sort_direction = (ListSortDirection)e.Column.SortDirection;

        dataGridPayables.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();

        dataGridPayables.Items.SortDescriptions.Add
            (new SortDescription(e.Column.SortMemberPath, sort_direction));
        dataGridPayables.Items.SortDescriptions.Add
            (new SortDescription("total_amount", sort_direction));
        dataGridPayables.Items.SortDescriptions.Add
            (new SortDescription("payment_actual", sort_direction));
        dataGridPayables.Items.SortDescriptions.Add
            (new SortDescription("status", sort_direction));
        e.Column.SortDirection = sort_direction;

        dataGridPayables.Items.Refresh();

        MessageBox.Show("SORT " + e.Column.SortMemberPath + " " + sort_direction.ToString());
}
```

I found out that the datagrid is sorted with the code above but when it leaves the method, C# sorts it again with ONLY the column selected and losing the multi sorting feature.

Please help

Comment: Did you try e.Handled="True" at the end of your sorting event ?

Comment: Thanks! though I already used that yesterday and that did the job. But I didnt know why it needed that. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop routing of event by marking it `e.Handled="True"`.

`Sorting` is a bubbling event which is raised on the source element and navigates up to the visual tree until it reaches the root element or until the bubbling is stopped by marking the event as handled.

These links will be helpful to understand `RoutedEvents` in WPF.

1. http://wpftutorial.net/RoutedEvents.html.
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx